# 1st party and 3rd party cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, http, cookies, http-headers, session-cookies

I'm trying to set up a web service that relies on cookies to identify the user.
Some times these are 1st party cookies, i.e. the users receive them on my site (e.g. my-site.com); other times the cookies are set/read from another site using an image served from my-site.com.

The problem is that in IE (at least in IE8), while in both cases the cookies are set and read correctly (persistent, not session cookies), they are treated as 2 separate cookies. I.e. my site assigns 2 different UIDs to the same user, and cannot perform the correct service for the other site.

I'm setting a P3P header in my HTTP response (without it 3rd party cookies are treated as session cookies).

In Chrome and Mozilla this works correctly, i.e. the cookie that was set as 1st-party is returned as 3rd-party when connecting from another site, and vice-versa.

### EDIT

Here's HTTP requests/responses dump from Fiddler:

HTTP Request: (1st party)

```
GET http://my-site.com/redirect_to?eid=100 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: he-IL
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: my-site.com
Cookie: uid=8943448674338503051
```

HTTP Response: (1st party)

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:22:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
P3P: CP="CUR CUS OUR BUS UNI NOI"
Location: http://google.com
Set-Cookie: uid=8943448674338503051; expires=Tue, 12-Jun-2018 12:22:31 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

HTTP Request: (3rd party)

```
GET http://my-site.com/pixel?eid=100 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: he-IL
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: my-site.com
Cookie: uid=6926889931739290944
```

HTTP Response: (3rd party)

```
HTTP/1.1 204 NO CONTENT
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:22:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
P3P: CP="CUR CUS OUR BUS UNI NOI"
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: uid=6926889931739290944; expires=Tue, 12-Jun-2018 12:22:12 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```